# saving to mongodb with mongoose fails but no error shown

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Am creating a nodejs bookstore app. **Books details which are *strings/numbers/booleans* are to be saved in MongoDB using mongoose** while the **book cover image is to be saved in an uploads folder in my root directory using multer**.Here is my **mongoose schema**:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//Creating schema and model
var BookDataSchema = new Schema({
title: String,
author: String,
isbn: String,
price: Number,
quantity: Number,
availability: Boolean,
description: String
});

var BookData = mongoose.model('BookData', BookDataSchema);
module.exports = BookData;
```

This is the code to perform the saving function:

```
router.post('/', function (req, res) {
  var newBook = new BookData({
    title: req.body.bkname,
    author: req.body.bkauthor,
    isbn: req.body.bkisbn,
    price: req.body.bkprice,
    quantity: req.body.bkquant,
    description: req.body.bkdesc
  });
      newBook.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log(newBook);
          console.log('Book Details saved successfully');
        }
      });
    }, function(req, res) {upload(req, res, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          res.render('admin', {
            msg: err
          });
        } else {
          console.log(req.file);
          return res.render('admin');
        }});}
      );
```

The main problem is when I console.log(newBook) or console.log(result) or check in mongo shell all I see is **{ _id: 5b4fdba80420890764ce13bf, __v: 0 }**, only the ***id*** that mongodb creates is displayed which means the other data is not saved and worse it does not proceed to the other callback function. Am not getting any error apart from this warning:

```
(node:1220) [DEP0079] DeprecationWarning: Custom inspection function on Objects via .inspect() is deprecated
```

I tested the code for saving the image excluding that for saving the other data and it worked fine. Kindly help on what could be the problem and also advise me on how I would ensure the admin page is rendered only after everything has been saved. See the whole project [in_this_git_repo](https://github.com/EricOuma/Catalogue)

Comment: Have you looked in the DB to be sure the data really isn't being saved?  The error you're getting seems to be related to the fact that you're trying to console.log the mongoose document rather than whether or not said document gets saved.  Note: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6438

Comment: Yeah, I checked the DB and all I see is {-id:8hfjhjfhguhfjhjghjg,-v}, so only the id is being generated and no data saved

Comment: This has nothing to do with multer; can you show your BookData schema and how you're registering it w/ mongoose and such?

Comment: while we're at it, show a console.log of req.body

Comment: console logging req.body gives an error of (Cannot read property 'body' of null) and ELIFECYCLE at the bottom

Comment: Where did you put the console statement?

Comment: I replaced console.log(result) with console.log(req.body)

Comment: Well, one problem is that the callback from node.save() is wrong in your code. Its first parameter is an error which will be null if there’s no error.  You’re overwriting the http response there instead.  If req.body is null, you likely don’t have the right bodyparser set up.

Comment: BTW consider using either `name` or `title` in schema/code.